# how can I divide log files for specific DB queries?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, logging, unix, plpython

Currently my db has a couple of triggers for some (not all) tables that get executed when a specific number of columns has been updated. I keep track if the triggers for those rows on a boolean column in the tables.

Id like to be able to log UPDATE and INSERT queries and the errors/warnings coming from them onto different files in my postgresql server as a singular log file can get quite big.

Ive thought of a couple of approaches to this problem and am looking for a better approach than these;

- have the triggers (plpython3) create seperate log files when they only get called (not a lot but they insert millions of rows onto different tables.
- write additional triggers that insert logging information onto another table (either by explicit means or a single JSON column)

thank you for your time and answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only a single PostgreSQL log file per database cluster, so you cannot have that out of the box.

Adding triggers that log to a file is an option, but a trigger (and the logging itself) can add significant performance overhead, certainly more than the PostgreSQL logging itself.

The route I would explore is this:

- Try to perform the actions you want to log with a different database user. If that is not easy, be creative: perhaps you can execute `SET ROLE`/`RESET ROLE` commands at strategic points in debug mode to become a different user.
- Enable logging for that user only:

  ```
  ALTER ROLE myuser SET log_min_duration_statement = 0;
  ```

Then it will be easier to evaluate the log, because it will be smaller.

Comment: Aha thanks, thats a creative solution, Ill try to make something like this happen and if all else fails fallback to writing a table but doing that Id definitely need to use UUIDs and/or md5 hashing of some sort, which might potentially be a question for another time !

Comment: I was looking at [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/311031/postgresql-is-it-possible-to-log-to-separate-files-per-database) which led me here. Is there not a way of (at least partially) doing what the OPs want to do using the [log_line_prefix (string)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html) which seems to have a large number of parameters which may be of use?

Comment: @Vérace You can configure the log format with that parameter, but not the log file. Of course you can use tools like `grep` to extract specific Information, but that's not what OP asked.