# PostgreSQL - is it possible to log to separate files per database?

Tags: postgresql, logging

I have multiple databases inside a single PostgreSQL instance. Is there some way to get it to use a separate log file for each database ?

Comment: How do you want to manage your log files? Can you please give any example?

Comment: I think that's a great idea - there's no way of modifying the log string and then filtering on that? +1

Comment: Take a look at the logline_prefix [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html) which may be of help?